# How can I convince IE to honor my explicit instructions to make a table column X pixels wide?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, html-table

Please consider this small but complete chunk of HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">
    span {overflow:hidden; white-space:nowrap;  }
    td {overflow:hidden; text-overflow:ellipsis}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0"  >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap; "><span>column 1</span></td>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap; "><span>column 2</span></td>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap; "><span>column 3</span></td> 
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

If you render the above in Chrome you'll see the effect I'm looking for.

However render it in IE8 or 9 the width and/or max-width is ignored.

So my question is how do get IE to simply let me specify the width of a cell explicitly?

BTW, I've tried various combinations of table-layout:fixed and using colgroup with cols and all sorts, nothing I've tried convinces IE to what I'm clearly asking it to explicitly do?

If I had any hair before starting this I wouldn't have any left by now.

Comment: I used windows and putting IE9 into IE8 document compatability.  IE9 and Chrome had identical output whereas in IE8 mode the columns widen a little although not to the full extent of the first failure.

Comment: BTW, you may note that for reasons I can't begin to fathom this question has be moved to SO. I should just stick to SO in future and not bother to try to ask Qs on the "correct" site since is seems really difficult to keep in mind what all the rules are :S

Answer (score 1):

try this,

```
<!DOCTYPE html >
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>

    <style type="text/css">
   span
{
    display: inline-block;
    *display: inline;
    *zoom: 1;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    -ms-text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
    word-wrap: normal;
    max-width: 30px;
    vertical-align: bottom;
}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing="0"  >
        <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap;"><span>column 1</span></td>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap;"><span>column 2</span></td>
               <td nowrap="nowrap" style="max-width:30px; width:30px; white-space:nowrap;"><span>column 3</span></td> 
             </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope its make sense..

Comment: Thanks that gets close but doesn't work in IE8.  The answer it seems is to set enable table-layout:fixed _and_ specify the table is 0px width.

Comment: Iam checking with IE8 its works fine on Windows. are you using mac ?